# Uncaught Error: Component DossiersListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am using the lazy loading and I have a parent component 'DossierRepairComponent' and a child component 'DossierListComponent'. When I run the project it gives me this error I am getting this error : `Uncaught Error: Component DossiersListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module` .

This is DossierRepairModule :

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 DossierRepairComponent],   
 imports: [CommonModule, DossierRoutingModule, SharedModule,
 DossierListModule],
 exports : [DossierListModule]
 })
 export class DossierRepairModule { }
```

And this is the DossierRepairRoutingModule :

```
const routes: Routes = [{ 
path: '',
component: DossierRepairComponent,
children : [{
  path : 'list',
  loadChildren: () => import('./dossier-list/dossier-list.module').then(m => m.DossierListModule),
}]
}]
@NgModule({
 imports: [
 RouterModule.forChild(routes)
 ],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DossierRepairRoutingModule { }
```

And this is the child module 'DossierListModule' :

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [DossierListComponent],
 imports: [
  CommonModule,
  DossierListRoutingModule,
  SharedModule,
 ]
 })
 export class DossierListModule { }
```

And the routing module 'DossierListRoutingModule':

```
const routes : Routes =[{  
path: '',
component: DossierListComponent
}]
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DossierListRoutingModule { }
```

I think everything is imported well I don't know what is the problem I tried to stop the server and run again with 'ng serve' but the problem persist ! Can anyone help me to resolve it please ?

Answer (score 0):

in the `DossierRepairModule` you're importing `DossierListModule` then you're lazy loading it.

Try removing it from the imports and exports.

Comment: I remove it and the error persist but when I re added it, I have another error `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DossierRepairModule'`

Comment: could you try to re-do it on stack blitz and share the link ?
Also you shouldn't import a lazy loaded module.

Comment: I re run the server I the old error display even when I removed the imports like you said  ! It is like he doesn't see the imports in DossierRepairModule